# Magento - disable product when stock reaches 0

Tags: php, magento, shopping-cart

I've been trying to get a clean solution to showing only products that have a filterable attribute IN STOCK, ie layered navigation filter Large will only show T-shirts that currently have Large sizes in stock.

I'd like to filter this before the productCollection is loaded, to keep the page loads quick(ish) - my latest venture is to try and set the item's status to disabled when its stock reaches 0, so that magento's core filtering will kick in on the layered navigation results page.

None of the methods i've tried have successfully set the status to disabled - I should be able to add something to CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Status.php updateStatus() right? or somewhere.. Something like:

```
/**
 * Update product status from stock item
 *
 * @param int $productId
 * @param string $productType
 * @param int $websiteId
 * @return Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status
 */
public function updateStatus($productId, $productType = null, $websiteId = null)
{
    if (is_null($productType)) {
        $productType = $this->getProductType($productId);
    }
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $item = $this->getStockItemModel()->loadByProduct($productId);

    $status  = self::STATUS_IN_STOCK;
    $qty     = 0;
    if ($item->getId()) {
        $status = $item->getIsInStock();
        $qty    = $item->getQty();
    }

    if($qty < 1)
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
    else 
        Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($product->getId(), $storeId, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

    $this->_processChildren($productId, $productType, $qty, $status, $item->getStockId(), $websiteId);
    $this->_processParents($productId, $item->getStockId(), $websiteId);

    return $this;
}
```

I've been at this for days and had no luck. If there's a more elegant solution I'm wide open

thanks

Comment: stock and products are different collections so you have to set disabled on product instead of stock/item

Comment: Thanks, your tip helped me figure out how to disable the product... I'm still having trouble getting the event right though. I hooked in to the cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after event but no dice. Magento is a nightmare

Comment: Well, it turns out that this actually does work... Since I develop locally, and use a remote database, it turns out that updates to Magento's core weren't getting used if they were on my local server. Another tally for magento..